iOS - How to be notified when a BLE device is connected to the phone?
The idea is, in the app you scan a list of BLE devices. You select one (or more) from it, and once any of those connect or disconnect with the phone, the app can be triggered and send a notification says Your device has connect/disconnect to (BLE device) (Regardless your app is running in the background or foreground or being terminated)
Seems it's doable on Android but after days of researching I haven't found any documentation can help.
Any insights ?
UPDATE:
Bellow is my code.
I've tried to connected/disconnected my airpods multiple times. When the app runs in the foreground, I can see both connected/disconnected events being invoked every time. But I only see disconnected events being invoked if the app runs in the background.
I also have Uses Bluetooth LE accessories and Acts as a Bluetooth LE accessory enabled.
public class BLEManager: NSObject, ObservableObject, CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate {
var myCentral: CBCentralManager!
@Published var isSwitchedOn = false
@Published var peripherals: [CBPeripheral] = []
@Published var connectingCBperipheral: CBPeripheral?
@Published var connectedCBperipheral: CBPeripheral?

func sendNotification(title: String, body: String) {
    let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
    content.title = title
    content.body = body
    content.sound = UNNotificationSound.default

    let request = UNNotificationRequest(identifier: UUID().uuidString, content: content, trigger: nil)
    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().add(request) { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error adding notification: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

override public init() {
    super.init()
    myCentral = CBCentralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: [CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey: "myCentralManagerIdentifier"])
}

public func startScanning() {
    myCentral.scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil)
}

public func stopScanning() {
    myCentral.stopScan()
}

public func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, willRestoreState dict: [String : Any]) {
    if let restoredPeripherals = dict[CBCentralManagerRestoredStatePeripheralsKey] as? [CBPeripheral] {
        for peripheral in restoredPeripherals {
            guard peripheral.name == connectedCBperipheral?.name else {
                return
            }
            
            sendNotification(title: "Restored", body: "Restored connection to \(peripheral.name ?? "device")")
            // You can also discover services, etc.
        }
    }
}

public func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
    isSwitchedOn = central.state == .poweredOn
    if isSwitchedOn {
        startScanning()
    } else {
        stopScanning()
    }
}


public func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDiscover peripheral: CBPeripheral, advertisementData: [String : Any], rssi RSSI: NSNumber) {
    guard peripheral.name != nil else { return }
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        if !self.peripherals.contains(where: { $0.identifier == peripheral.identifier }) {
            self.peripherals.append(peripheral)
        }
        if let connectingCBperipheral = self.connectingCBperipheral, self.connectedCBperipheral == nil {
            self.connect(to: connectingCBperipheral)
        }
    }
}

public func selectPheripheralToObserveConnection(_ item: CBPeripheral) {
    connectingCBperipheral = item
    
}

func disconect() {
    guard let item = connectedCBperipheral else { return }
    myCentral.cancelPeripheralConnection(item)
}

func connect(to peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    guard let cbperipheral = myCentral.retrievePeripherals(withIdentifiers: [peripheral.identifier]).first,
    cbperipheral.state != .connected else { return }
    
    peripheral.delegate = self

    myCentral.connect(cbperipheral, options: [:])
}

public func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral) {
    guard peripheral != connectedCBperipheral else { return }
    print("Connected to \(peripheral.name ?? "Unknown") ", peripheral.identifier.uuidString)
    connectedCBperipheral = peripheral
    peripheral.delegate = self
    sendNotification(title: "Connected", body: "Connected to \(peripheral.name ?? "device")")
}

public func centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral, error: (any Error)?) {
    print("Did disconnect to \(peripheral)", error?.localizedDescription ?? "")
    connectedCBperipheral = nil
    sendNotification(title: "Disconnected", body: "Disconnected from \(peripheral.name ?? "device")")
}


According to apple documentation there are delegate methods which are called on connect and disconnect
optional func centralManager(
    _ central: CBCentralManager,
    didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral
)

optional func centralManager(
    _ central: CBCentralManager,
    didDisconnectPeripheral peripheral: CBPeripheral,
    error: (any Error)?
)

You will need the following code to begin with your task
import CoreBluetooth

guard CBManager.authorization == .allowedAlways else {
     // Prevents the system from generating an CBManager
     // TODO: Replace with catchable error
     throw FatalError(“Grant Always Allowed to use Application”)
}
var BluetoothThread = DispatchQueue(label:”BluetoothThread”, qos:.userInteractive)
// TODO: Replace <#CBCentralManagerDelegate?#> with a instance or nil
// TODO: Replace <#Secret Recovery Key#> with key for recovering your CBCManager Permissions
var CBManager = CBCentralManager(delegate:<#CBCentralManagerDelegate?#>,queue:BluetoothThread,options:[“ CBCentralManagerOptionRestoreIdentifierKey”:NSString(“<#Secret Recovery Key#>”)])


You can also use automations in Shortcuts to detect specified devices if this is the only purpose of your app

Have tried those, but I only didDisconnected is being invoked when I close the connection, the didConnect isn't being invoked

@TungVuDuc this may be relevant then https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38192535/centralmanager-didconnectperipheral-is-never-called

@TungVuDuc also if you can provide some code in your original question that might help

I've updated the post to include my code. Please have a look, Thank you

See Core Bluetooth Background Processing for iOS Apps for full docs. You'll start a long-running connection request to the known PeripheralID. Whenever the device comes into range, the OS will perform the connection and your app will be launched and you'll be made aware of the connection. As long as your app continues to communicate with the device, it'll keep running in the background and you will be able to see a "disconnect" event on the delegate if it occurs.

Thanks for your response, I'm able to see "disconnect" event on background but there's no "connect" event occurs when the BLE device connect with the phone again.

What do you mean by "connect with the phone again?" Are you calling connect()? BLE devices do not spontaneously connect unless the central, which you control, reaches out. Generally you would attempt to reconnect in the disconnect callback. Maybe you're confusing a classic BR/EDR (audio) connection for a BLE connection?

Hi I've update my post to include the code I have. Would be great if you can have a look

"Acts as a Bluetooth LE accessory" is incorrect here. You are not doing that. AirPods are not primarily BLE devices, and the OS may or may not connect and disconnect the BLE connection specifically in response to your app's requests (this is true of every BLE-capable device, but particularly AirPods which have a lot of Apple-proprietary hooks into the hardware and OS). If your goal is to write an app that knows when AirPods are connected or disconnected at all times, that's probably not possible. It definitely will not have a simple Stackoverflow answer.

Specifically when you say "I've tried to connected/disconnected my airpods multiple times" if you mean "connected as an audio device" that has nothing at all to do with the code you've written here. That's not a BLE connection. It's generally an A2DP (BR/EDR) connection, though Apple has proprietary protocols they use as well, so it may not even be that. Many earbuds have audio connections for audio and separate (unrelated) BLE connection for control.

Thanks for your insights, a lot of new terms here for me :) My main target for this aplication is the bluetooth on the car (basically, I want to know when the phone is connect/disconnect with CarPlay) but I want the app supports as much devices as possible

Testing for connections to CarPlay, particularly in the background, is going to be very challenging; probably impossible in the general case. And the things you're looking at here are about connections between a device and your app, not a device and the phone. Apps almost never get access to that kind of information. You should probably search for your actual use case, and then post a question targeted at it specifically. General questions about Bluetooth are unlikely to be helpful since Apple highly restricts general Bluetooth access, with specific APIs for specific use cases.
